# Forbidden: SizeLimit field disabled by feature-gate for EmptyDir volumes

Tags: kubernetes, volume

I want to limit the size of `EmptyDir` in kubernetes-1.7.0, but got the following error:

```
[spec.volumes[3].emptyDir.sizeLimit: Forbidden: SizeLimit field disabled by feature-gate for EmptyDir volumes
```

So is the `sizeLimit` for `EmptyDir` not enabled by default? Is there a way to enable the feature?

Answer (score 0):

Running `kubelet` `kube-apiserver` `kube-controller-manager` and `kube-scheduler` with this flag `--feature-gates=AllAlpha=true` could solve this problem.

Comment: looks like we can pass this flag to other process also, api server, control server etc.

Comment: Yes, it needs `apiserver` and `controller-manager` to set this flag too. But I find that `kubelet` doesn't report storage capacity to `apiserver` and it makes Pods that limit storage size failed to run.